# Fibonacci numbers for $3 \leq n$ , proof by induction

Tags: analysis, proof-writing, induction

Let $P_{1}, P_{2}, P_{3}$ represent the *Fibonacci* numbers. Show by induction that claim ($n$): $P_{n} \geq (\sqrt{2})^{n-1}$ for $n \geq 3$

Step $1$)  is comprehensible. 
I cant get past:

$P_{n+1} ≥ (\sqrt{2})^{n-1+1}$

$P_{n} + P_{n -1} ≥ (\sqrt{2})^n$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your statement clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

As you suggested, you have
$$
P_{n+1}
 = P_n + P_{n-1}
 \ge \left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{n-1} + \left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{n-2}
 \ge 2 \cdot \left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{n-2}
$$

Can you finish this?

**UPDATE**

Note that this relies on Strong Induction (which is equivalent to regular induction but easier to prove sometimes, like here). Namely, the inductive step is that if $P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_n$ all hold, then $P_{n+1}$ holds as well...

**UPDATE 2**

Note that $2 = \left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2$, so what is $2 \cdot \left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{n-2}$?

Comment: I cant move on, a leading hint?

Comment: @Seanchristian see 2nd update

Answer (score 1):

We need two initial cases:
$$
F_3=2\ge2^{(3-1)/2}=2\tag1
$$
and
$$
F_4=3\ge2^{(4-1)/2}=2^{3/2}\tag2
$$
since squaring $(2)$ gives $9\gt8$.

Suppose the statement is true for $n-1$ and $n-2$, then
$$
\begin{align}
F_n
&=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}\\
&\ge2^{(n-2)/2}+2^{(n-3)/2}\\
&\ge2\cdot2^{(n-3)/2}\\
&=2^{(n-1)/2}\tag3
\end{align}
$$